# Show Previous Selected Date in UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

How to show previous selected date value when reopen UIDatePicker?

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePickerView: UIDatePicker!

func setupDatePicker(){
    setUpSelectedDateValue(date: datePickerView.date)
    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleDatePicker), for: .valueChanged)
    datePickerView.setValue(UIColor.init(hex:"#2D75FF"), forKeyPath: "textColor")
    datePickerView.setValue(false, forKey: "highlightsToday")

    if UserDefaults.value(forKey: UserdefaultKey.datePickerKey) != nil {
        datePickerView.setDate(UserDefaults.value(forKey: UserdefaultKey.datePickerKey) as! Date, animated: false)

    }
}

@IBAction func okAction(_ sender: Any) {
    delegate?.updateDate(selectedDate: datePickerView.date)
    self.selectedPickerDate?(datePickerView.date)
   UserDefaults.setValue(datePickerView.date, forKey: UserdefaultKey.datePickerKey)

    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

On click OkAction `datePickerView.date` set as current value for UIDatePicker when reopen the controller again.

Comment: Added UserDefaults after clicking okAction, Its worked, But is it ideal solution?